# Minify HTML output, but preserve certain tags

Tags: php, string, escaping

I am working on a function to minify the HTML code of my pages by stripping unnecessary spaces, linebreaks and tabs, also comments from it.
However, I would like to preserve the tags starting with

```
 "<!-- google_ad_section... -->"
```

as they tell Google which sections of my page to emphasize.

My current code snippet to trim the code is this one, found at another spot on this great site. I understand as much as parameter encoding to realize that the first part of the 2nd parameter clears all comments .. but how can I preserve all tags containing the "google_ad_section" string?

```
function sanitize_output2($buffer){
return preg_replace(
array(
    '/ {2,}/',
    '/<!--.*?-->|\t|(?:\r?\n[ \t]*)+/s'
),
array(
    ' ',
    ''
),
$buffer
);
}
```

Comment: It's normally called "to minify" rather than "to sanitize".

Comment: thanks for the hint, I changed the title.

Answer (score 2):

How about this solution:

- run your HTML through [DOMDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/de/class.domdocument.php)
- use the option [preserveWhiteSpace](http://www.php.net/manual/de/class.domdocument.php#domdocument.props.preservewhitespace) with `false` to remove all extra whitespaces
- filter all comments that are not like the one you need

Maybe it could look like this:

```
$html = '<html>[…]</html>';

$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false; 
$doc->loadHtml($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$comments = $xpath->query('//comment()');
foreach ($comments as $comment) {
    if (!preg_match('/^google_ad_section /', $comment->nodeValue)) {
        $comment->parentNode->removeChild($comment);
    }
}

$html = $doc->saveHTML();
```

I wrote this by heart and didn't test it. So maybe it's not 100% accurate.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to check out the strip_tags() function; especially the second parameter.

```
strip_tags($html_string,$allowable_tags);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

And the trim() function as well; again checkout that second parameter.

```
 trim($html_string,$charlist)
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

You might also want to look at Apache's mod_deflate which will compress the output.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_deflate.html

But that only work for HTML files. To get the PHP output compressed you'll need to work with zlib.output_compression = On either in the php.ini file for site-wide or at runtime with

```
ini_set("zlib.output_compression", "On");
```

http://php.net/manual/en/zlib.configuration.php

Comment: thanks, but according to the documentation I can't use it for this particular purpose, as the tag is formatted like a comment and also contains spaces, both of which the strip_tags() function "kills".